# WebView APP - How to open links in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

all links open in WebView and I can not go back to the previous view of the APP.

How can I specify that links are opened in the Safari and not in the WebView of my APP?

What do I have to change in my code?

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Many thanks for your efforts!

greeting
Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below:

In Objective-C:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url ])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

In Swift:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think it useful for you:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(yourUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(yourUrl)
}
```